# What should be considered as component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was learning what component is and what should be considered as component. As I found out component is considered as a certain block of a web page that can be reused and I hope I am right with this statement. But as you can see in the picture below button "What should I do" and add caption with input box together are considered as components. Why? those buttons are not reused anywhere in the same page so why should they be components. As far as I know, Component is a block that is reused in the same page several times[image: picture]

Comment: That is totally up to you and how you want to construct your app.

Comment: This is very subjective.  Some people break EVERYTHING into components.  For example.


```const Header = ({ text }) => { return `<h1>${text}</h1> }```

Comment: re-usability isn't necessarily the only reason to make something a component.

Comment: Dear downvoter, be careful with what the question means.

Comment: @KevinB, please can you give your own advice on what should be considered as component

Comment: @topGun everything.

Comment: @KevinB, you wrote "re-usability isn't necessarily the only reason to make something a component". What can be the reasons to make something as component at least on your personal experience

Comment: performance (in some cases,) separating logic, just because,

Comment: @KevinB, what do you think what would be consider as a component in the above picture. Yes, you let me know that you would consider "everything" as a component. But considering reusability, would it a norm to regard header only as a component since I intend to use it in several pages but the buttons and input are not.

Comment: buttons and inputs should be components. the things that hold teh buttons and inputs should be components. many of the things inside the blue box should be separate components.

Comment: @KevinB, but buttons and inputs are not reused I just use them only once. Should I consider components as something that help separate logic rather than help with reusability? Gosh so hard to be starter :)

Comment: If you need the features making it a component gives you, make it a component. it's simple.

Comment: @aviya.developer, good day, sorry but wanted to kindly ask you one question. From your experience, how would you divide the above UI into components in React.Would you consider each element, for example, in header there are h1 tag and p tag. Would you divide h1 and p into separate components. What I do not get is that how deep would you go to break ui into components? I really hope your kind advice

Comment: @Dickens I would not break up the `<h1>` and `<p>` since these are basic element in `html`. A component should be something that is easy for you to reproduce when needed, and an `<h1>` and `<p>` element tags are already that. So you would use a component to actualy bundle up a couple of things together into 1 reusable component.

Comment: @aviya.developer, thank you a lot for your advice. But, in some React tutorials authors make a logo as separate component as well as input box even if both are easy to reproduce. Why to make a components for such easy-to-create things as logo or input box, I mean, logo and inputbox are as easy to create or, say, reproduce as h1 and p tags. Is it because logo and inputbox can be reused EVEN IF they are easy to create?

Comment: @aviya.developer, please I really need your help

Comment: @Dickens I honestly can't say about the other tutorials. If the logo element is something that requires a specific file it makes sense to make into a reusable component, since if the file changes you can just change the source component file and any instance of the logo will get updated. That's usually the logic behind compartmentalization. It should lead you in your decisions about fragmentation of a react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexibility.

If you particularly style your button one way and it takes a lot of copy-paste to use it elsewhere, why not make it a component and just call it.

Alternatively if it's fairly simple, you can just write it as is and move on instead of going through the overhead of making it a component.

It's entirely up to you.

Don't take the re-usability aspect too serious. Think of components as parts of a machine. You can order a motherboard, screen, mouse, keyboard... for a computer, or you can order the laptop as a whole. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on you. The idea is to make as much reusable components as possible in React, if you stick to this formula your life will not only be easier but also your project will look clean and proper.